# photo edition: centre photo of a projector presentation taken at an angle?

Tags: image-editing

I have taken a bunch of photos with my phone of a slide presentation, but I took them sitting at an angle from where the projector was. How can edit the images so that they are re-centered with respect to the content of the presentation in the image? Preferably in an scripted manner, since I have a whole bunch of them.
EDIT: I initially would just want to correct the skew in an automated fashion.

Comment: do you wish to center only or correct the skew?  was it hand held or on a tripod?  if it was hand held, there would be no consistancy to the location of the data, so are you asking for something that could "track" the location of the screen? Or could you skew all the pictures the same and then do a lite crop, and hope that most of them were not offset too far? Photoshop actions could be used to repeat that action, but knowing hand held pictures, best would be to call the person giving the presentation and Beg them to send it to you. After effects has tracking features, but not easy for this.

Comment: Perhaps better off at [photo.stackexchange.com](http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq)?  You're being a little vague for our liking. :)  Which OS? Which software? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

The feature you are looking for will be called **perspective correction** in most graphics apps. There is a [perspective correction plugin for the Gimp](http://registry.gimp.org/node/24537). Here is a [tutorial on performing batch operations in Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/). There is also a [tutorial on performing perspective correction using Panotools](http://wiki.panotools.org/Perspective_correction).